# Log Android user wakeup/unlock

Tags: android, service, unlock, wakeup

I'm trying to create an application that has a constant running service which will log and display to the user everytime they unlock or change the phones state from screen off to screen on.
Is this possible without using the Log cat through the P.C?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using Broadcast Receiver. Android system sends always broadcasts for specified changes. You can handle this broadcasts using Broadcast Receiver.

Example:

We will create a new Broadcast Receiver to handle the Screen On and Screen Off state:

```
    public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //we will handle here the activities which will tell us that
        // the screen state has changed
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
           //write log that the screen is off
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
           //write log that the screen is on
        }
      }
   }
```

All what you need is to declare this BroadcastReceiver in Android Manifest.xml
file:

```
 <receiver android:name="yourpackage.PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And after that you should start your PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver on yout 
Service onCreate Method:

```
//...
public void onCreate(){
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

   PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver pSReciever = new PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver();
   registerReceiver(pSReciever, filter);
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks  A LOT!

Just one more question. Is there a way to tell when the user actually unlocks the phone and log it, not just power on the screen?

Comment: If anyone comes across this, just replace ACTION_SCREEN_ON with ACTION_USER_PRESENT. It recognises when someone unlocks their phone